Group owner cannot write to file despite group permissions
I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have a system user/group systembob and a system user alice.
alice is a member of the systembob group, and has been for quite some time:
$ getent group systembob
systembob:x:990:alice

$ groups alice
alice : alice systembob

The system has been through many login cycles and restart cycles since alice was added to the systembob group, so it is certain that the current shell session recognizes alice's group membership.
I have a folder resources/ with ownership and permissions like so:
$ ll -hd resources/
drwxrwxr-x 3 systembob systembob 4.0K Jul 18 11:51 resources/

Since alice is a member of systembob, she has folder access (x) and write permissions (w) on resources/, so she should be able to write files into it.  Indeed, when I act as alice using sudo, she can:
$ sudo -u alice touch resources/test.txt
$ ll -h resources/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alice alice    0 Jul 18 11:46 test.txt

Now, the problem.  The resources/ folder contains a file data.txt with ownership and permissions like so:
$ ll -h resources/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 systembob systembob 2.7K Mar 10  2023 data.txt

Again, since alice is a member of systembob, she has write permissions on data.txt and should be able to write data into it.  In this case, however, she cannot:
$ sudo -u alice echo "TEST" > resources/data.txt
-bash: data.txt: Permission denied

Yet, if I open up permissions so that "other" can write to data.txt, I find that alice can then write data to it:
$ sudo chmod o+w resources/data.txt

$ ll -h resources/data.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 systembob systembob 5 Jul 18 14:19 data.txt

$ sudo -u alice echo "TEST" > resources/data.txt
{no error or other output}

$ cat resources/data.txt
TEST

It seems like alice is not being properly understood as a member of the systembob group.  Why is this?
This question is similar to those here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054888/linux-why-cant-i-write-even-though-i-have-group-permissions

Group member cannot write even with write permission


The accepted answer to both is that since alice was just added to the group systembob, the current shell session does not yet recognize her group membership.  As I explained above, that is not the issue here.  And to be absolutely certain, I did fully logout of the machine and log back in; the results are the same.
Another proposed solution in the first link above is ACL rules.  That is also not the issue here, since I do not use ACL rules, and you can clearly see from the output of ll that neither resources/ nor data.txt have the + sign indicating relevant ACL rules.
I am not using SELinux.
Edit
As indicated in the duplicate (sudo redirection permission denied), the issue is the redirect operator >.  The shell executes the echo command as alice, and then returns to acting as my own user for the redirect.  Opening write permissions for "other" allowed me to write to the file, not alice.
To confirm, I replaced the echo ... > command with a cp command for alice to write over the file data.txt.  As expected, alice could cp with group ownership, but not without.
